# Extracting operation name using Xpath1.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to extract operation name from incoming request.

**Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://visa.com/sd/pc/service" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-058C2E38D966BC3F2E15372874505064" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ser:ReportRequest FromDate="2017-11-01"  Timezone="GMT" ToDate="2017-11-30" TransactionType="All"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Xpath used**: `/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*`

**Getting the output**: `<ser:ReportRequest xmlns:ser="http://visa.com/sd/pc/service" FromDate="2017-11-01" Timezone="GMT" ToDate="2017-11-30" TransactionType="All"/>`

**expected output**: `ReportRequest`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the expected output `ReportRequest` you have to modify your XPath expression to

```
local-name(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*)
```

This gets the local-name of the first child in XPath-1.0.
If you'd want to get the names of all children you'd have to iterate over the core path expression and get the `local-name()` of each item separately.

---

If you'd have XPath-2.0 available, you could simplify that and use the following expression

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*/local-name()
```

to get all names of all the children of the `soapenv:Body` element.